# Approximating the marginal likelihood in Bayesian Model Comparison

Tags: bayesian, estimation, likelihood, model-comparison

Given some data $y$, my interest centers around a collection of models $\{\mathcal{M}_1,\mathcal{M}_2,\cdots,\mathcal{M}_L\}$ representing competing hypotheses about $y$.  Each model $\mathcal{M}_l$ may be characterized by a model-specific parameter vector $\theta_l$ and sampling density (likelihood) $f(y\,|\,\mathcal{M}_l,\theta_l)$.

where $\pi(\theta_l\,|\,\mathcal{M}_l)$ and $\pi(\theta_l\,|\,y,\mathcal{M}_l)$ are the prior and posterior distributions of $\theta_l$  and $m(y|\mathcal{M}_l)$ is the marginal likelihood of $y$ given $\mathcal{M}_l$.  Following Chib (1995) I write
$$
m(y|\mathcal{M}_l)=\frac{f(y\,|\,\mathcal{M}_l,\theta_l)\pi(\theta_l\,|\,\mathcal{M}_l)}{\pi(\theta_l\,|\,y,\mathcal{M}_l)}
$$

Applying Bayes theorem yet again I can calculate the marginal posterior probability of each model.
$$
p(\mathcal{M}_l\,|\,y)=\frac{m(y|\mathcal{M}_l)p(M_l)}{\sum_{i=1}^L m(y|\mathcal{M}_i)p(M_i) }
$$

***My question is: what methods are best for actually estimating $m(y|\mathcal{M}_l)$ when the posterior distribution is not known? Or similarly when the prior is non-conjugate?***

I know of both this estimator 
$$
m(y|\mathcal{M}_l)=\int_{\Theta_l} f(y\,|\,\mathcal{M}_l,\theta_l)\pi(\theta_l\,|\,\mathcal{M}_l)d\theta_l = E[f(y\,|\,\mathcal{M}_l,\theta_l)\,|\,\mathcal{M}_l]
$$
$$\approx \frac{1}{G}\sum_{g=1}^G f(y\,|\,\mathcal{M}_l,\theta^{(g)}_l)
$$
Where $\theta^{(1)}_l,\theta^{(2)}_l,\cdots, \theta^{(G)}_l$ are draws from the prior $\pi(\theta_l\,|\,\mathcal{M}_l)$
But Newton and  Raftery (1994) says this estimator converges very slowly and recommends the harmonic mean estimator instead
$$
\hat{m}(y_t|\mathcal{M}_l)=\bigg[\sum_{g=1}^G \frac{1}{ f(y\,|\,\mathcal{M}_l,\theta^{(g)}_l)} \bigg]^{-1}
$$
where parameters are drawn from the posterior. Although consistent, the harmonic mean estimator is noted for being unstable by Chib (1995) and others.  My references are 20 years old so I would think researchers have found better methods but I have not had much luck finding them on my own. I was wondering if anyone here knew about good practical means of estimation.

- Chib, Siddhartha, “Marginal Likelihood from the Gibbs Output,” Journal of the American Statistical
  Association, 1995, 90 (432), pp. 1313–1321.
- Newton, Michael A. and Adrian E. Raftery, “Approximate Bayesian Inference with the Weighted
  Likelihood Bootstrap,” Journal of the Royal Statistical Society. Series B (Methodological), 1994, 56
  (1), pp. 3–48.

Comment: We wrote a [comparison study](http://arxiv.org/abs/0910.2325) about those methods with Jean-Michel Marin a few years ago. And yes the Newton-Raftery method should be avoided at all costs!

Comment: A useful keyword from the physics literature is _thermodynamic integration_, also going under the name of _path sampling_ in statistics.

Comment: @Xi'an Thank you for the references I read over both the comparison study you provided and the paper on bridge sampling by Andrew Gelman and Xiao-Li Meng cited therein. It was helpful (though I admittedly don't understand all of it).  My situation is a bit particular.  I am comparing structural economic models.  The likelihoods are based on linear regression models, but the economic theory requires sign restrictions on the parameters.  I impose these sign restrictions in my priors, and do not have very much data so it is not easy to choose approximations to the target density.